# free product in specific bundled product?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1.4

I want to offer an item for free in specific bundled products, so for example in bundle 1 you can choose to get item A or B for free and in bundle 2 you can't and you have to pay a price for it.

This process happens before you put anything in the shopping cart, so I obviously cant use shopping cart rules

Comment: you can used magento event observer functionality to set product price before load.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?